# Is there any way to give Github merge access to people for all branches except master?

Tags: github

I would like to give merge access to my co-workers. But, I do not want them to be able to merge their code into master (or another branch I maintain: staging). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ask them to **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)** the repo and make [PR (pull request)](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

You can then inspect and/or reject any PR made to the master branch.

The [GitHub branch protection](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) doesn't prevent fast-forward pushes, to the fork is the best option.